# Opengl es 2.0 live wallpaper on Nexus 7 (2012)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, live-wallpaper

I'm developing a live wallpaper in android with opengl es 2.0. Started code is [enter link description here](http://www.learnopengles.com/how-to-use-opengl-es-2-in-an-android-live-wallpaper/). I want to reload textures on `onSurfaceChanged` method of renderer linked to wallpaper (and GLSurfaceView). On my Nexus 7 (2012) with tegra 3, when i try to do this, sometimes i obtain the following error:

```
08-11 03:54:41.128: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(26131): NvRmChannelSubmit: NvError_IoctlFailed with error code 1
08-11 03:54:41.130: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(26131): NvRmChannelSubmit failed (err = 1, SyncPointValue = 19952985, returning = 0)
08-11 03:54:41.130: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(26131): NvRmChannelSubmit failed (err = 196623, SyncPointValue = 0)
```

Is anybody got the same problem?